# What is the best way in VB.Net to launch bat scripts one after the other?

Tags: vb.net, process

I've got a VB.Net program that calls a bat script, waits for it to succeed or timeout, do some actions, calls another bat script, waits for it to succeed or timeout and so on.

What I have done is declaring the following elements :

```
Dim mainProcessHandler As New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim mainProcess As Process
```

And use them all along the program like that :

```
mainProcessHandler.FileName = "something_01out18.bat"
mainProcessHandler.Arguments = "-d"
mainProcessHandler.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
mainProcess = Process.Start(mainProcessHandler)
```

Then further :

```
mainProcessHandler.FileName = "something_02out18.bat"
mainProcessHandler.Arguments = "-s"
mainProcessHandler.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
mainProcess = Process.Start(mainProcessHandler)
```

And a third, a fourth, etcetera: I've got multiple calls such as described above and can't convince myself that's the way to do it.

What is the correct way in VB.Net to handle this issue?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing but the best way to do it is a matter of opinion and opinion-based questions are off-topic here. I will just say that personally, I declare variables with as narrow scope as possible and as close to their usage as possible. I also don't reuse objects unless they are expensive, which a `ProcessStartInfo` definitely is not.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before asking. Your question is opinion based.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I'm not a professional developer and the underlying question here was to know if the used method was suitable and not a massive waste of resources or a complete code heresy using out-of-scope tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the submitted code is suitable to launch bat scripts one after the other. Any reflexion about which other way to do it could be better may lead to an opinion-based discussion which is improper on stackoverflow.